# Show that the eigenvector basis of $A$ is also one of $f (A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

> Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field and $f \in \mathbb{K}[X]$ a polynomial over $\mathbb{K}$. Let $A \in \mathbb{K}^{n \times n}$ be a diagonalizable matrix. Show that $f(A)$ is also diagonalizable.

I hope you can help me, I have problems with showing something in general without examples.

Comment: Welcome to MSE, Noobie. I recommend you learn basic MathJax/$\LaTeX$ so you can write properly on this website.

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ is diagonalizable, there exists a diagonal matrix $D$ and an invertible matrix $S$ such that $D=SAS^{-1}$. If we write out $f(x)=c_nx^n+...+c_1x+c_0$, then what happens if we multiply the matrix $f(A)$ on the left by $S$ and on the right by $S^{-1}$? You might find the fact that $(SAS^{-1})^k=SA^kS^{-1}$ to be helpful.

Comment: I know how A should look like, and you write out f(x), but how does f(A) look like. I dont see that sorry.

Comment: Just plug in $A$ at each point where there is an $x$

Comment: f(A) given by Victor.                                                                             But how does the S look like for polynomial. When we talk about diagonaziable then there needs to be eigenvector and because of it a λ. I think  I need to put it somewhere :/

Comment: It doesn't matter what S is, just the property it has. You can multiply:
$SF(A)S^{-1}=S(c_n A^n+...+c_1A+c_0I)S^{-1}$
and then distribute and use the fact I gave

Answer (score 0):

1. A generic polynomial over $\mathbb{K}$ has the form $p(x) = c_0 + c_1x + c_2x^2 + ... + c_nx^n, c_i \in \mathbb{K}$.
2. When you use a matrix $A$ as input for the polynomial, you get $ f(A) = c_0I + c_1A + c_2A^2 + ... + c_nA^n$.
3. Now you just have to conclude that, since $A$ is diagonalizable, all of the matrices in the above polynomial are also diagonalizable. If you understand diagonalizability, this is rather obvious. But I'll just say that every matrix in the above polynomial satisfies

$$  PA^nP^{-1} = D^n$$